# Nhibernate Linq is null on left join

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Is there an easy way to do the following Nhibernate Linq statement

```
var query = from r in myTable.Query<MyTable>()
            where r.Child == null
            select r
```

The linq query above produces something similar to

```
SELECT MyTable.Id FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ChildId is null
```

it doesn't reference the child table and check if the left join is null like the following

```
SELECT MyTable.Id FROM MyTable 
      LEFT JOIN ChildTable ON MyTable.ChildId = ChildTable.Id
WHERE ChildTable.Id is null
```

Comment: Which version of NHibernate do you use?

Comment: I am using Nhibernate 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from r in myTable.Query<MyTable>()
        where r.Child.Id == null
        select r
```

Comment: Didnt expect it to work since the child id is an int, but hey it did. Thanks

Comment: Needed to add "#pragma warning disable CS0472" before doing this (and restore after)